# Erlang: What are strategies for dealing with huge SASL crash reports?

Tags: erlang, sasl

When my app crashes, I get a crash report that takes 5 minutes to scroll by. What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Look at the Error Report on top :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pipe the crash dump to a file. The important information is probably at the top.

You could do what Hynek was saying above and configure a sasl error logger handler for the crash dumps: http://erlang.org/doc/man/sasl_app.html

The default is tty which dumps to your screen and is not terribly helpful as you mentioned. But you could specify that it should use the sasl_report_file_h instead. Then the dump gets logged to a file for easier perusal.

Additional Links:

- [Crash Report documentation in the SASL user guide](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/sasl/error_logging.html#2.3) - how to read a crash dump
- [Report Browser utility for Sasl error reports](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/sasl/error_logging.html#2.5) - might be useful for finding out what when wrong